# How to know whether drawable of image view from bitmap or resources

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

```
ImageView iv;
Drawable d = imageView.getDrawable();
if (d instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
    if (d is not resources) // How to check ??? iv.setImageResources(resId);
        ((BitmapDrawable) d).getBitmap().recycle();
}
```

I want to recycle bitmap except resources drawable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not check like that... but this approach may help you...

```
    private void setImage(Drawable drawable,boolean isFromResource) {
        imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        imageView.setTag(isFromResource);
    }

    private void recycle() {
        Object object = imageView.getTag();
        if(object != null && object instanceof Boolean) {
            boolean isFromResource = (Boolean) object;
            if(!isFromResource) {
                Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
                if(drawable != null && drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
                    BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
                    Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
                    bitmap.recycle();
                    imageView.setImageDrawable(setToNewDrawable);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: true that, you cant check if its from resources or not, this is best possible solutions as per me.